# Display All of a Div that is nested in a Div with Overflow Auto

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the hovercard plugin http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard. In one of my div's I have

```
overflow:auto;
```

Inside that div I have several links with hovercards attached to them. When I hover over the link and the hovercard appears it only shows the portion of the hovercard that is visible **within** the parent div. This of course is because of the overflow:auto.

How can I make the hovercard appear above our outside of the parent div and not have its viewable area limited by the parent div?

As an aside, I have to use overflow:auto in the parent div. That can't be changed.

Here is the code I am working with:

HTML

```
<div class="demo-live">
    <strong>Hover over the red text to see the hovercard in action:</strong>
    <p>
        jQuery by
        <div class="hc-preview" style="z-index: 0; ">
            <label id="demo-basic" class="hc-name" style="z-index: 0; ">John Resig</label>
            <div class="hc-details" style="width: 400px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: none; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; ">
                <img class="hc-pic" src="http://ejohn.org/files/short.sm.jpg">
                <p>John Resig is an application developer at Khan Academy. He was a JavaScript tool developer for the Mozilla Corporation. He is also thecreator and lead developer of the jQuery JavaScript library.</p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        is a cross-browser JS library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of                         HTML. It was released in January of 2006 at BarCamp NYC. Used by over 46% of the                            10,000 most visited websites, it's the most popular JavaScript library in use today.
    </p>
</div>​
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //plugin script for demo basic---
    var hoverHTMLDemoBasic = '<p>' + 'John Resig is an application developer at Khan Academy. He was a ' + 'JavaScript tool developer for the Mozilla Corporation. He is also the' + 'creator and lead developer of the jQuery JavaScript library.<p>';

    $("#demo-basic").hovercard({
        detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoBasic,
        width: 400,
        cardImgSrc: 'http://ejohn.org/files/short.sm.jpg'
    });

});
```

CSS

```
.demo-live{
max-width:300px;
overflow:auto;    
}​
```

**Demo**: of what is going on: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7y7t/)

Comment: Can you post some actual code

Comment: no problem Chad just added a fiddle to my question. Thanks

Comment: do you need the overflow auto?

Comment: does it do any harm if you removed the overflow when you pop the tooltip? then add it back in

Comment: That was all I could think of too. The reason overflow is so important is because we are using infinitescroll. So, if the overflow is removed suddenly you see a ton of content and then when you leave the hovered element the content is hidden again. Which is no good.

Comment: Worked on it over the weekend, and can't seem to find a fix for it. The removing of overflow causes lots of "hidden" cotent to all of a sudden appear when it shouldn't.
Is it possible to remove the overflow and add a display:none to all content that should not be seen? aka, that is currently outside the height of the parent div

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can remove the overflow on hover and add it back in on unhover but I don't know if that fits your page or not